# SpriteKit - Make a sprite move similar t another sprite

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm making a type of a platformer ( think super mario but in a top-down view style ) game and i want my main character to move with the platform it has contact with.

So i used this:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody;
SKPhysicsBody *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}



if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PlatformCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == PlayerCategory) {
_contact = YES;



}
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
if (_contact) {
_player.position = CGPointMake(_platform2.position.x, _platform2.position.y +     10);
}
}

}
```

It kinda worked, and now my player is moving with that SPECIFIC platform when it touches it, but that's not a very practical way for doing it because i will be randomly generating platforms. So how t achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKPhysicsBody has a property called node, which is the parent sprite it's attached to. In your collision method, test if the physics body is of collision category platform, then:

```
SKSpriteNode *thisCollidedPlatform = (SKSpriteNode*) nameOfPhysicsBody.node
```

And then use the position of thisCollidedPlatform to set the player position.